# What does %FS (Full Scale) represent in load cell?

Tags: load-cell, specifications

Lets say that a load cell has these specifications:

- Rated Load = 500 g
- Rated output = 1 mV/V
- Excitation voltage = 12 V
- Creep = 0.02 %FS / min

Then the output range should be 0--12 mV.

Does %FS mean out of the maximum of the output voltage range? That is FS = 12 mV

Then the creep could be converted to 0.0002 * 12 mV/min = 2.4 μV/min?

**EDIT:** Of course it should be 0.0002 * 12 mV/min and not 0.02 * 12 mV/min. But then I got the original question answered, FS stands for the maximum rated output voltage.

Comment: Of rated (maximum) load, whatever output voltage corresponds to.

Comment: No, creep is 0.02% of 12mv/min, not 0.02 * 12mV/min.

Comment: Well if you got your question answered, upvote and/or accept the answer.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Your comments were the ones which answered my questions. Andy's answer showed what percentages are, not answering the original question.

Answer (score 1):

If full-scale is 12 mV then 0.02% of 12 mV is 2.4 μV.

- 100%  = 12000 μV
- 10%   = 1200 μV;
- 1%    = 120 μV
- 0.1%  = 12 μV
- 0.01% = 1.2 μV

So after 1 minute, you might expect a reading of (say) 1 mV to creep to 1.0024 mV or 0.9976 mV.

Comment: The original question was not meant to be about percentages, that was just a typo. See edit note of post.

Comment: @RobinHellmers you are confusing me. I'm not a mind-reader so telling me it wasn't meant to be about this or that tells me nothing about what it was meant to be about. [See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKrn6.png) if the question is answered.

Comment: ”Does %FS mean out of the maximum of the output voltage range?”

Comment: Yes it does mean that. FS = full-scale.